# Lambda function not calling auth0 methods via Auth0 node-auth0 SDK

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, auth0

I've got a lambda function which is triggered when a message is added to the SQS queue.

The message contains a userId which I was hoping to connect to [Auth0 node SDK](https://github.com/auth0/node-auth0#management-api-client).

my `GetUserDetails` (below) fires as the `console.log` is viewable in CloudWatch

I can see in the Auth0 logs that a token request is made from the `new ManagementClient` call but then nothing after that.

example of my code

```
import { ManagementClient } from 'auth0';

const auth0 = new ManagementClient({
  domain: 'xxx.auth0.com',
  clientId: 'xxx',
  clientSecret: 'xxx',
  scope: 'read:users update:users',
});

const GetUserDetails = userId => {
  console.log('userId', userId); <-- This fires and can be seen in CloudWatch

  auth0.getUser({ id: userId }, (err, resp) => { <-- Nothing happens no errors, no user details
    if (err) {
      console.log('my error', err);
      return err.message;
    }
    console.log(resp);
    return resp;
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work using this format:

```
auth0
  .getUser(userId)
  .then(function(users) {
    console.log(users);
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Comment: Hi Dan, do you have this running in an express server or something similar or in a lambda function? As I've just done exactly the same and nothing has been console logged